# Error 404 not correct work

Tags: web-config, http-status-code-404

I have some problem with work web-page 404.
Error 404 to the second level of links works fine, but when typing a link above the 3rd level (see screenshot), the web page is not displayed correctly.
For example [enter link description here](http://www.pro-okna-dveri.ru/1/2/3)
The settings were made through the hosting panel by simply turning on and indicating the 404 error page.
The support team answers that this is a problem on the part of the developer.
What can be wrong?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2j7n.png)

Comment: Can you locally browse that page ? What do you mean by second level and third level.

Comment: You can try clicking the link  http://www.pro-okna-dveri.ru/1/2 
And you will see the correct error page 404.
If you click the link http://www.pro-okna-dveri.ru/1/2/3 then there will be an error.

Comment: is your local version working fine ?

Comment: If you check the url for the images all of them are pointing to `http://www.pro-okna-dveri.ru/1/attachments/Image/404-primer-1.jpg.` which doesn't exist

Comment: Here is the error page 404 at URL http://www.pro-okna-dveri.ru/err404 works correctly does not float.
The same URL http://www.pro-okna-dveri.ru/err404 is listed in the settings of the hosting-panel Plesk on the recommendations of the hosting provider.
Example www.pro-okna-dveri.ru/1 works, more www.pro-okna-dveri.ru/1/2 works, but from the third level of the link www.pro-okna-dveri.ru/1/2/3 page swims. Why? URL http://www.pro-okna-dveri.ru/err404 works correctly

Comment: you can have rewrite rule in web.config file which will redirect  /1/2/3 url to 404 page and all other levels above three redirects to 404 page.